# Failing to Attach Debugger to in Cloud Explorer - Requested Action Could Not Be Completed

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I've started to get the error below in the latest version of VS 2015 when I try to attach to a web process in the Cloud Explorer panel. It usually works the first time or two and then fails when I try again. Only fix I've found is to open and close VS.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting this issue as well. I've had to workaround it by manually attaching my debugger instead. Try taking a look at this solution and see if it works for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983836/how-do-i-remote-debug-a-net46-asp-net-core-application-in-azure